# Trouble Implementing Hashed Passwords Authentication in Shiro 1.3.0

Tags: apache, jsf, authentication, jsf-2.2, shiro

Okay— I’ve been spinning my wheels here for a week trying to figure this out myself, and I’ve gotten nowhere. The Shiro documentation/tutorials out there seem to be too fragmented between the various versions and deprecated design paradigms, such that I am having a hard time figuring out exactly how to implement this myself. Even the official documentation leaves a lot of blanks that leave the novice dazed and confused. I’ve been following this (now somewhat outdated) BalusC tutorial on setting up Apache Shiro authentication in a JSF application (Link: http://balusc.blogspot.sg/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html). I was able to following the article up through the **“Hashing the password”** section, which is where the article really starts showing it’s age (claims no support for salting), and drove me to look elsewhere for implementing this crucial feature.

Below are the basics of my development environment.

**IDE:** NetBeans 8.0.2
**Server:** TomEE 1.7.1
**DB:** MySQL 5.5
**Application Frameworks:**
JSF 2.2
OmniFaces 1.8.1 (hasn’t yet come into play, other than me using o:form tags in anticipation of further use)
JPA 2.0 (as TomEE 1.7.1 claims to not support 2.1, at least that’s what NetBeans tells me...)
Apache DeltaSpike 1.2.1 (Core and JPA modules ONLY; assists with CDI+JPA persistence)
Apache Shiro 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT (Core and Web modules ONLY)

**What I was able to get working:**
- Authenticate users from MySQL database; reading raw/plain-text usernames and passwords
- Registration form to save new users in raw/plain-text format to the users table

Here the relevant configurations for this:
**shiro.ini**

```
[main]
# As per BalusC's guide for Ajax aware custom User Filter. Do not use @WebFilter annotation or web.xml to register this filter!
user = ds.nekotoba.filter.FacesAjaxAwareUserFilter
user.loginUrl = /faces/public/login.xhtml

#Define Realm
jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT role FROM userroles WHERE user_id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?)

#Define Datasource
dataSource = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
dataSource.serverName = localhost
dataSource.port = ####
dataSource.user = ********
dataSource.password = ********
dataSource.databaseName = ********
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $dataSource

#Add realm to securityManager
securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm

[urls]
/faces/javax.faces.resource/** = anon
/faces/public/login.xhtml = user
/faces/public/app/** = user
```

**User Create Method** `create()`

```
public Long create(User user) {
    //Set created date
    user.setCreatedDate(new Date());

    //Persist to DB
    em.persist(user);
    return user.getId();
}
```

**Programmatic User Login Method** (from custom JSF login form) `login()`

```
public void login() throws IOException {
    try {
        SecurityUtils.getSubject().login(new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password, remember));
        SavedRequest savedRequest = WebUtils.getAndClearSavedRequest(Faces.getRequest());
        Faces.redirect(savedRequest != null ? savedRequest.getRequestUrl() : Globals.HOME_URL);
    } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
        Messages.addGlobalError("不明なユーザ、また試してみてください。");
        ae.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is all pretty simple, and works— but my problem comes in when trying to convert all of this to use hashed passwords. I was able to get a hashed password, and associated salt saved to the DB from a modified create method— but I can’t seem to get the right settings in my `shiro.ini` to successfully login using these hashed users.

Updated `shiro.ini` (to implement new hashed password matching). Note the added `PasswordService`, `PasswordMatcher`, and updated `authenticationQuery` which now includes the salt column. I’ve only included the updated portions of the ini file for brevity.

```
#Include salt column in authentication query
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password, salt FROM users WHERE username = ?

#Use Default PasswordService/Matcher. This should use SHA-256, with 500,000 iteration hashing.
passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
passwordService = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
passwordMatcher.passwordService = $passwordService
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $passwordMatcher
```

Updated `create()` method, which hashes the password, and extracts the salt for separate storage in the DB.

```
public Long create(User user) {
    HashingPasswordService hps = new DefaultPasswordService();
    //Hash password given in registration form using the DefaultPasswordService,
    //this should use the same defaults at the PasswordService/Matcher defined in shiro.ini
    Hash hash = hps.hashPassword(user.getPassword());
    //Set user.password to hashed version for persisting to DB
    String hashedPass = hash.toBase64();
    user.setPassword(hashedPass);
    //Get related salt from hash and set in user object for persisting to DB
    String salt = hash.getSalt().toBase64();
    user.setSalt("salt");

    //Set created date
    user.setCreatedDate(new Date());

    //Persist to DB
    em.persist(user);
    return user.getId();
}
```

This is where I get stuck— I assume at this point I need to update the login method to also handle the hashing of the inputted password by the user by retrieving the salt from the DB, and hashing the submitted password and then matching to the stored hashed password from the DB— but all attempts I have tried have been unsuccessful. And trying to authenticate with the `login()` method from above just gets me an error stating the supplied credentials did not match...

I have tried implementing some of the code in this (Japanese) tutorial (日本語が少し知っていますよ), but it seems a bit off to me (Link: http://d.hatena.ne.jp/apyo/touch/20120603/1338739210). Isn’t hashing/salting supported by Shiro? I don’t see why I should have to rewrite/override Shiro methods (as per that tutorial) to accomplish authenticating a user against hashed data, something that is claimed to be supported by the framework.  I would think there is some delivered method out there I should be using, I just can’t find the right one. Of course, it could be that the way I am hashing/storing/retrieving the user data is causing issues… I am just too new to the framework to know. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
Okay-- So it seems like perhaps it is "the norm" to have to override a method in the delivered JdbcRealm to implement verification of user password+salt. I have implemented the following custom realm, but am getting a `NullPointerException` when the method is called.

**CustomJdbcRealm.java** (based on above linked tutorial)

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationToken;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.SaltedAuthenticationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.SimpleAuthenticationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService;
import org.apache.shiro.codec.Base64;
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.Sha256Hash;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm;
import org.apache.shiro.util.ByteSource;

/**
 * @author mousouchop
 *
 * Modification Log: 2015-01-17 Original.
 */
public class CustomJdbcRealm extends JdbcRealm {
    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    /**
     * 認証情報を返却する。
     * @param token
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    protected SaltedAuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token)
        throws AuthenticationException {

        UsernamePasswordToken upToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;
        String username = upToken.getUsername();
        SaltedAuthenticationInfo info = null;

        System.out.println("TEST######## TOKEN-UN: "+upToken.getUsername());

        // Here I switched out a plain JDBC query for a JPA query (Perhaps this is part of my problem?)
        List<String> queryResults = em.createNamedQuery("User.ps")
                .setParameter("username", username)
                .getResultList();
        System.out.println("TEST######## RESULT CT: "+queryResults.size());
        String password = queryResults.get(0);
        String salt = queryResults.get(1);
        System.out.println("TEST######## PW: "+password);
        System.out.println("TEST######## SLT: "+salt);

        // ShiroデフォルトのjdbcRealmをそのまま使い、SecurityManagerをshiro.iniで初期化する方法だと、
        // saltStyleが設定できない。saltをAuthenticationInfoに渡す方法は用意されているが、
        // DefaultPasswordServiceを使うとバグ？でsaltが無視されてしまう(まだ調査中です)
        // とりあえずブログ用に強引にゴリゴリとHashクラスを生成する。
        // ハッシュアルゴリズムが固定になってしまっているが、
        // まぁよしとする。別に動的に生成しなければいけない場面もないだろうし。
        Sha256Hash credentials = Sha256Hash.fromBase64String(password);
            credentials.setSalt(ByteSource.Util.bytes(Base64.decode(salt)));
        // SimpleHashクラスとDefautoPasswordServiceでハッシュ回数のデフォルト値が異なる。
        // 整合性が取れてないとも言えるが、これはこれでいいのかな。
    credentials.setIterations(DefaultPasswordService.DEFAULT_HASH_ITERATIONS);
        // principals,credentials,realm名を設定して、AuthenticationInfoを生成する。
        info = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(username, credentials, getName());

        return info;
    }
}
```

Of the "TEST" output lines that I have-- the first returns the entered username... I get the `NPE` before any of the others print out. Maybe I will try using plain JDBC calls in just this one class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I did a little more digging and it seems I can't use CDI injection directly into the Shiro JDBC realm like I tried to do above... There is an conflict between the management Shiro is doing with it's own beans, and CDI with its own. I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27230798/1165803) which seems to try to make a bridge between CDI and Shiro by initializing the realm, inserting the User DAO into the realm from CDI, and then binding the realm instance to JNDI to later retrieve in the `shiro.ini`, however, once again, all of the examples/documentation are so fragmented that I couldn't quite get it all to  work.

As such, I just used the custom `JdbcRealm` verbatim from the Japanese tutorial I listed in my question. I didn't want to have to stray outside of CDI for DB interaction within my beans, but because the JDBC datasource is already defined in the `shiro.ini`, all the connection information and queries pull in right from there without needed to hard-code/redefine them in the custom realm. At least there isn't total duplication of code I gues... Here's my final, working, custom `JdbcRealm` bean pasted here for the sake of completeness:

**CustomJdbcRealm.java**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationToken;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.SaltedAuthenticationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.SimpleAuthenticationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService;
import org.apache.shiro.codec.Base64;
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.Sha256Hash;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm;
import org.apache.shiro.util.ByteSource;
import org.apache.shiro.util.JdbcUtils;

/**
 * @author mousouchop
 *
 * Modification Log: 2015-01-17 Original.
 */
public class CustomJdbcRealm extends JdbcRealm {

    /**
     * 認証情報を返却する。(Override AuthenticationInfo method)
     */
    @Override
    protected SaltedAuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        UsernamePasswordToken upToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;
        String username = upToken.getUsername();
        Connection conn = null;
        SaltedAuthenticationInfo info = null;

        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            // DBよりパスワード、SALTを取得する。(Get password and salt from DB)
            String[] queryResults = getPasswordForUser(conn, username);
            String password = queryResults[0];
            String salt = queryResults[1];

            // ShiroデフォルトのjdbcRealmをそのまま使い、SecurityManagerをshiro.iniで初期化する方法だと、
            // saltStyleが設定できない。saltをAuthenticationInfoに渡す方法は用意されているが、
            // DefaultPasswordServiceを使うとバグ？でsaltが無視されてしまう(まだ調査中です)
            // とりあえずブログ用に強引にゴリゴリとHashクラスを生成する。
            // ハッシュアルゴリズムが固定になってしまっているが、
            // まぁよしとする。別に動的に生成しなければいけない場面もないだろうし。
            Sha256Hash credentials = Sha256Hash.fromBase64String(password);
            credentials.setSalt(ByteSource.Util.bytes(Base64.decode(salt)));
            // SimpleHashクラスとDefautoPasswordServiceでハッシュ回数のデフォルト値が異なる。
            // 整合性が取れてないとも言えるが、これはこれでいいのかな。
            credentials.setIterations(DefaultPasswordService.DEFAULT_HASH_ITERATIONS);
            // principals,credentials,realm名を設定して、AuthenticationInfoを生成する。
            info = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(username, credentials, getName());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            final String message = String.format("次のユーザーの認証中にSQLエラーが発生しました。ユーザー：[%s]%n", username);
            throw new AuthenticationException(message, e);
        } finally {
            JdbcUtils.closeConnection(conn);
        }
        return info;
    }

    /**
     * DBよりユーザーに紐づくパスワードとSALTを取得する。 org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealmよりコピー。
     * saltStyleに関する記述を除去。
     *
     * @param conn
     * @param username
     * @return
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    private String[] getPasswordForUser(Connection conn, String username) throws SQLException {

        String[] result;
        result = new String[2];
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            // 親クラスにデフォルトで用意されているSQLか、
            // shiro.iniにもパスワード取得用SQLを定義できる。
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(authenticationQuery);
            ps.setString(1, username);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            // 複数レコードが取れた場合のチェックフラグ
            boolean foundResult = false;
            while (rs.next()) {

                // ループ2周めだとfoundResultはtrue=エラー
                if (foundResult) {
                    throw new AuthenticationException(
                            String.format("ユーザー：%sのデータが複数あります。ユーザー名に対応するユーザーは必ず一人でないといけません。%n", username));
                }

                // password
                result[0] = rs.getString(1);
                // password_salt
                result[1] = rs.getString(2);
                foundResult = true;
            }
        } finally {
            JdbcUtils.closeResultSet(rs);
            JdbcUtils.closeStatement(ps);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

So, this along with the **updated** `shiro.ini` and `create()` method in my question above should allow you to implement hashed user authentication using Apache Shiro 1.2.*/1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.