# How do I define the initial context factory in shiro.ini?

Tags: java, jndi, shiro, apache-tomee

In my Shiro application, I am using the `JndiRealmFactory` to define my realms. I Register my realms like this:

```
Hashtable<String, String> args = new Hashtable<>();
args.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(args);
ctx.bind("realms/MyRealm", myRealm);
```

However, Shiro cannot find `realms/MyRealm`. I think the reason is, that I Need to define the `JndiRealmFactory`'s jndiEnvironment, which contains the `Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY` property. However, I don't know how to set this property in my `shiro.ini`:

```
realmFactory.jndiEnvironment = ?
```

I am running my application on TomEE.

My current `shiro.ini` looks like this:

```
realmFactory = org.apache.shiro.realm.jndi.JndiRealmFactory
realmFactory.jndiNames = realms/MyRealm
```

Comment: Post your full shiro.ini there is no need of realmFactory.jndiEnvironment

Comment: The code I posted is all I got regadring the registration of realms. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not supposed to bind at runtime anything in the EE context. You can probably define it in tomcat as a resource or resources.xml (tomee specific) then just use a standard lookup to read the value (no special properties passed to InitialContext.

Comment: I tried to implement the second answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507629/inject-cdi-managed-bean-in-custom-shiro-authorizingrealm

How do I accomplish this using resources? How do I instantiate my realms and do constructor injection?

Comment: before going in the explanation which are quite long I wonder if it wouldn't be easier to just use the cdi integration of pax https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXSHIRO/CDI+Support ? Would make the referencing not relying on JNDI at all. If not it is a matter of defining your realm through https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html