# CDI enabled shiro filter

Tags: cdi, shiro

there is enough information about creating CDI-enabled shiro Realms. In my case I need CDI in a custom shiro filter, would that be possible?

```
public class com.moc.CustFilter {

  @Inject
  private MyUtil myUtil;

  // .... using myUtil

}
```

shiro.ini

```
[main]
custFilter = com.moc.CustFilter

[urls]
/web/** = custFilter
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inject CDI managed bean in custom Shiro AuthorizingRealm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507629/inject-cdi-managed-bean-in-custom-shiro-authorizingrealm)

Answer (score 0):

This code in the constructor of the filter was enough for me

```
private SomeUtils utils;

public ApisecAuthcFilter() {
    try {
      BeanManager beanManager = (BeanManager) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
      Bean<SomeUtils> utilsBean = (Bean<SomeUtils>) beanManager.resolve(beanManager.getBeans(SomeUtils.class));
      CreationalContext<SomeUtils> creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null);
      utils = utilsBean.create(creationalContext);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
      throw new SomesException();
    }
  }
```

Comment: So you found the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507629/inject-cdi-managed-bean-in-custom-shiro-authorizingrealm