# Pac4j with Shiro and Keycloak - how can I manage my Permissions (Authorization)

Tags: shiro, pac4j

I´m currently try to setup Shiro with Keycloak.
I searched on the internet and found some shiro.ini settings for setup a OIDC Config with Keycloak.
I´ve setup Shiro before without Keycloak authentication - everything was based on JDBC realm.
I´m managing my permissions with Shiro. I have in my app some SQL tables (permission_role_object). Therefore I have those JDBC queries:

```
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = ...
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = ...
```

My question is, how can I have a relationship to my pac4jRealm (= Keycloak authentication) to my SQL table for the permissions?
I guess I need also to add something in the shiro.ini:

```
pac4jRealm.userRolesQuery = ...
pac4jRealm.permissionsQuery = ...
```

This is my current shiro.ini

```
[main]
#### Session
sessionIdCookie=org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie
#sessionIdCookie.path = /
sessionIdCookie.httpOnly = true
sessionIdCookie.name = sid
sessionIdCookie.domain = localhost
sessionIdCookie.maxAge=28800000
sessionIdCookie.secure = true
sessionIdCookie.sameSite = LAX

sessionManager=org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
sessionManager.sessionIdCookie=$sessionIdCookie
sessionManager.sessionIdCookieEnabled=true
securityManager.sessionManager=$sessionManager
# Session Timeout nach 8 Stunden
sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout= 28800000

sessionListener1= de.dpunkt.myaktion.util.MySessionListener1
sessionManager.sessionListeners=$sessionListener1

# Session validation = 5 minutes
sessionManager.sessionValidationInterval = 300000


#sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
#securityManager.sessionMode=native


sessionValidationScheduler=org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.ExecutorServiceSessionValidationScheduler
sessionValidationScheduler.interval = 60000
sessionValidationScheduler.sessionManager=$sessionManager
sessionManager.sessionValidationScheduler=$sessionValidationScheduler
sessionManager.deleteInvalidSessions=true
#sessionFactory=org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.OnlineSessionFactory
#sessionManager.sessionFactory=$sessionFactory
#securityManager.subjectDAO.sessionStorageEvaluator.sessionStorageEnabled = false

#Keycloack
oidcConfig = org.pac4j.oidc.config.OidcConfiguration
oidcConfig.withState = false
oidcConfig.discoveryURI = http://localhost:9009/auth/realms/myapp/.well-known/openid-configuration
oidcConfig.clientId = myapp
oidcConfig.secret = 112345679465456
oidcConfig.clientAuthenticationMethodAsString = client_secret_basic
oidcClient = org.pac4j.oidc.client.OidcClient
oidcClient.configuration = $oidcConfig

clients = org.pac4j.core.client.Clients
clients.callbackUrl = http://localhost:8080/api/callback
clients.clients = $oidcClient

pac4jRealm = io.buji.pac4j.realm.Pac4jRealm
pac4jRealm.principalNameAttribute = preferred_username
pac4jSubjectFactory = io.buji.pac4j.subject.Pac4jSubjectFactory

pac4jRealm.principalNameAttribute = preferred_username
securityManager.subjectFactory = $pac4jSubjectFactory

#usernameAuthorizer = myapp.util.UsernameAuthorizer
#usernameAuthorizer.elements = ${user1},${user2}

config = org.pac4j.core.config.Config
config.clients = $clients
#config.authorizers = username:$usernameAuthorizer

oidcSecurityFilter = io.buji.pac4j.filter.SecurityFilter
oidcSecurityFilter.config = $config
oidcSecurityFilter.clients = oidcClient
oidcSecurityFilter.authorizers = +username

# DataSource
ds = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource
ds.serverName = localhost
ds.user = root
ds.password = test1234
ds.databaseName = myapp
ds.useSSL = false
ds.serverTimezone = Europe/Berlin

# password hashing specification, put something big for hasIterations
sha512Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
sha512Matcher.hashAlgorithmName=SHA-512
sha512Matcher.hashIterations=1

# Configure JDBC realm datasource.
jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = select password FROM user where UPPER(email)=UPPER(?) and status = 'ACTIVE'
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT r.unique_name FROM permission_role_employee pe JOIN permission_role r ON pe.permission_role_fk  = r.permission_role_id JOIN employee e ON pe.employee_fk = e.employee_id JOIN user u ON e.user_fk = u.user_id WHERE UPPER(u.email)=UPPER(?) AND pe.delete_flag = false
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = SELECT p.unique_name FROM permission_role_object po JOIN permission p ON po.permission_fk  = p.permission_id JOIN permission_role r ON po.permission_role_fk = r.permission_role_id WHERE UPPER(r.unique_name)=UPPER(?) AND po.delete_flag = false
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $sha512Matcher

# Realm for Token Login
tcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
tcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
tcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT token FROM api_token WHERE token = ?
tcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT r.unique_name FROM permission_role_employee pe JOIN permission_role r ON pe.permission_role_fk  = r.permission_role_id JOIN employee e ON pe.employee_fk = e.employee_id JOIN api_token t ON t.employee_fk = e.employee_id WHERE UPPER(t.token)=UPPER(?) AND t.delete_flag = false
tcRealm.permissionsQuery = SELECT p.unique_name FROM permission_role_object po JOIN permission p ON po.permission_fk  = p.permission_id JOIN permission_role r ON po.permission_role_fk = r.permission_role_id WHERE UPPER(r.unique_name)=UPPER(?) AND po.delete_flag = false
tcRealm.dataSource = $ds

# AuthStrategy
authenticator = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator
authcStrategy = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.AtLeastOneSuccessfulStrategy

authenticator = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator
securityManager.authenticator = $authenticator
securityManager.authenticator.authenticationStrategy = $authcStrategy
securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm, $tcRealm, $pac4jRealm

# Caching
cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

# Using default form based security filter org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter
authc = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter
authc.loginUrl = /common/login.jsf
authc.successUrl = /portal/dashboard.jsf


# Redirect to an access denied page if user does not have access rights
#[roles]
#roles.unauthorizedUrl = /common/access-denied.jsf
#perms.unauthorizedUrl = /accessdenied.jsp

anyofpermission = com.myapp.util.CustomPermissionsAuthorizationFilter

# Protected URLs
[urls]
/service = noSessionCreation, anon
    
## OTHER
/WEB-INF/layout/portal/** = authc
/portal/** = authc
/admin/** = authc
/community/** = authc
```

Answer (score 0):

The Shiro `JdbcRealm` is an `AuthorizingRealm` with JDBC capabilities.

The `pac4jRealm` is also an `AuthorizingRealm` with pac4j logic, there is no JDBC capability in the `pac4jRealm`.

Thus you cannot configure things only in the `shiro.ini` file.

You should certainly create a pac4j `AuthorizationGenerator` which retrieves the roles and permissions from the database and set it to the `OidcClient`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you have a coding example how this can look like? I´m very new in Pac4j :/

Comment: See: https://github.com/pac4j/buji-pac4j-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/pac4j/demo/shiro/RoleAdminAuthGenerator.java and https://github.com/pac4j/buji-pac4j-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/shiro.ini#L19

Comment: Great, thanks.... So this mean: I will do a database request in the `RoleAdminAuthGenerator` class.
With `profile.getUsername()` I got the emailaddress (my user) and now I will search in my Permission table against this username?
But where do I store the permission? Is this than like this?  `profile.addAuthenticationAttribute("mypermissionName", true);`

Comment: Depending on the version of pac4j, you can do: `profile.addPermission()` or `profile.addAttribute(Pac4jRealm.SHIRO_PERMISSIONS, Arrays.asList("PERM1", "PERM2"));`

Comment: Ok, thanks... but first I need to have a solution for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77043005/keycloak-apache-shiro-and-pac4j-installation-configuration

Comment: Is the `KeycloakRolesAuthorizationGenerator` always is use for Keycloak? I defined `roleAdminAuthGenerator = com.myapp.util.Pac4jRoleAdminAuthGenerator
oidcClient.authorizationGenerator = $roleAdminAuthGenerator` It´s called, but afterwards always also `KeycloakRolesAuthorizationGenerator` ?

Comment: and also how can I `@Inject`or use `@EJB`in  `Pac4jRoleAdminAuthGenerator` to make a call to my database?

Comment: `oidcClient.authorizationGenerator = $roleAdminAuthGenerator` uses the `setAuthorizationGenerator` method which internally calls the `addAuthorizationGenerator` method. That's why both authorization generators are used. Using `oidcClient.authorizationGenerators = $roleAdminAuthGenerator` (notice the `s` of `authorizationGenerators`) should call the `setAuthorizationGenerators` method which only makes an assignment

Comment: Injecting beans in a realm defined in the `shiro.ini` file is a more global question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507629/inject-cdi-managed-bean-in-custom-shiro-authorizingrealm and https://shiro.apache.org/jakarta-ee.html