# Configure Apache Shiro to load [urls] section fully from JPA Entities

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, shiro

I can't seem to find an example to load the [users] AND [urls] from my JPA objects.
I want to use shiro.ini for [main] section only.

The source code of what I achieved so far is this:
[Unable to @Inject my DAO in a Custom Apache Shiro AuthorizingRealm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605038/unable-to-inject-my-dao-in-a-custom-apache-shiro-authorizingrealm)

Is there any example where [users] (user/pass) AND [urls] (roles, permissions) are FULLY loaded from database? I can't seem to find that anywhere. I'm looking for it for 1 week now.

Comment: are you using the org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener in your web.xml?

Comment: I'm using my own CustomEnvironmentLoaderListener that extends EnvironmentLoaderListener. It is being declared at web.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some long research, the "best" solution I came up with was this:

shiro.ini

```
[main]
jsfFilter = com.test.security.CustomAuthorizationFilter
jsfFilter.loginUrl = /login.jsf

[urls]
/** = jsfFilter
```

// You can add the methods to filter Ajax requests described by BalusC inside this filter.
CustomAuthorizationFilter.java

```
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter extends AuthorizationFilter {

@Override
    public boolean isAccessAllowed(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, Object mappedValue) throws IOException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        if (!httpRequest.getRequestURI().startsWith(httpRequest.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) {

            Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

            AuthenticatingSecurityManager authenticatingSecurityManager = ((AuthenticatingSecurityManager) SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager());

            PrincipalCollection principals = subject.getPrincipals();
            JPARealm jpaRealm = (JPARealm) authenticatingSecurityManager.getRealms().iterator().next();
            AuthorizationInfo authorizationInfo = jpaRealm.getAuthorizationInfo(principals);

            for (String permission : authorizationInfo.getStringPermissions()) {
                if (pathsMatch(permission, request)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        } else {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `pathsMatch(permission, request)` method will try to validate/compare the received string permission with the path the user is trying to access.
This filter relies on ALWAYS having an authenticated user.
If the `subject.getPrincipal()` is null, more coding is necessary.
If anyone needs the whole code, let me know.

Comment: Hi MBarni, I'm also having similar kind of requirement to save and load URL authorizations on database so can you please share the whole code. So I can understand the way it can be implement.