# Why I am getting NULL pointer Exception when injecting the bean as follows?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, javabeans, shiro, java-ee-8

I am using Apache Shiro for Authentication/Authorization. I am good with the Authentication part using signed JWT. But, as for the auth part I am facing a NULL pointer exception on when accessing the object. Please guide me where I am mistaken...

This class implements **RolePermissionResolver** from Apache shiro, and whenever a request is fired it needs to pass through the overriden function if the REST request is annotated with **@RequiresPermissions()** or **@RequiresRoles()**

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Default
public class JpaRolePermissionResolver implements RolePermissionResolver {
  @Inject
  PermissionRoles permissionRoles;
  @Override
  public Collection<Permission> resolvePermissionsInRole(String roleString) {
    /*PermissionRoles permissionRoles = new PermissionRoles();
    permissionRoles.getAllPermissionsForRole();*/
    permissionRoles.getAllPermissionsForRole();
    if(roleString.equals("adminplus")) {
      return List.of(new WildcardPermission("canupdate:read"));
    } else if(roleString.equals("mod")) {
      return  List.of(
        new WildcardPermission("troopers:read"),
        new WildcardPermission("troopers:create"),
        new WildcardPermission("troopers:update")
        //, ... but not delete.
      );
    } else if(roleString.equals("user")) {
      return List.of(new WildcardPermission("troopers:read"));
    }
    return List.of();
  }
}
```

```
public interface IRolePermission extends Serializable {
   HashMap<String, PermissionRoles> getAllPermissionsForRole();
}
```

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PermissionRoles implements IRolePermission {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "default")
  EntityManager em;
  private String role;
  private String permission;

  public PermissionRoles() {
  }
  public PermissionRoles(String role, String permission) {
    this.role = role;
    this.permission = permission;
  }

  public String getRole() {
    return role;
  }

  public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
  }

  public String getPermission() {
    return permission;
  }

  public void setPermission(String permission) {
    this.permission = permission;
  }

  @Override
  public HashMap<String, PermissionRoles> getAllPermissionsForRole() {
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT er.name as role_name, ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(ep.name), ',') as permission_name " +
      "FROM ecommerce_roles er " +
      "JOIN ecommerce_role_permission erp ON er.id = erp.role_id " +
      "JOIN ecommerce_permissions ep ON ep.id = erp.permission_id " +
      "WHERE er.status = 1 AND ep.status = 1 " +
      "GROUP BY role_name";
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery);
    List<Object[]> rolesPermission = query.getResultList();
    System.out.println(sqlQuery);
    HashMap<String, PermissionRoles> permissionRoles = new HashMap<>();
    for(Object[] object : rolesPermission) {
      permissionRoles.put((String) object[0],new PermissionRoles((String) object[0], (String) object[1]));
    }
    return permissionRoles;
  }
}
```

```
@Inject
PermissionRoles permissionRoles;

@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
@RequiresPermissions("canupdate:read")
public String hello() {
  permissionRoles.getAllPermissionsForRole();
  return "User resource";
}
```

Knowing that when calling **permissionRoles.getAllPermissionsForRole();** in the REST Request i.e. the **hello** function is working properly, but not in **JpaRolePermissionResolver**, any idea why ? please help !

Comment: What object is null? Can you include the stacktrace?
Do the equivalent `Subject.hasPermissions(*)` methods work for you?

Comment: The `PermissionRoles`  Object, looks like Apache Shiro is not configured with JAVA EE CDI. I think I need to handle it manually, if you can help with this approach please

Comment: So I was right, found this fix here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605038/unable-to-inject-my-dao-in-a-custom-apache-shiro-authorizingrealm ... And I was able to conifgure Shiro with JAVA EE CDI